# Java Multi-catch exception with both child and parent

Tags: java, multi-catch

What happens if I try to catch both an Exception and say an InterruptedException like this:

```
try {
  someCode();
} catch (Exception e) {
  doSomething();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
specialTreatmentForThisException();
}
```

In this case InterruptedException extends Exception. What happens if an InterruptedException is thrown? Will it go to that catch-clause and for all other Exceptions the first clause?

The desired outcome is to handle one exception thrown in a special way, and all the rest of the exceptions in one way.

Thanks and best regards.

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?

Comment: Did you try? Your code won't work out and results in compilation error. That would answer your question :)

Comment: are you not getting compilation error?

Comment: That wouldn't compile as `catch (InterruptedException e)` could never be reached. Specific exceptions must be caught first, i.e. first `InterruptedException` then any other exception in your case.

Comment: The order of catch clauses should be from more specific Exception (as `InterruptedException` ) until the most general Exception (as `Exception`)

Comment: I have not tried, what's a good practice way to achieve what I would like to do? I have an interrupted exception that I need to handle in a special way. For all other exceptions I want to do something else.

Comment: @PrinceofSweden this isn't about "good practice", this is about "how it works". the first catch is taken into account first, then the second, then ... since Exception catches all, the compiler won't allow you to add the second catch block. You'll need to put that first catch block first. that'll work and 'll do exactly as you want

Comment: Follow specific to generic approach, First catch `InterrupedException` then catch generic `Exception`

Answer (score 0):

As already added by [Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/637853/thomas) and [User](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7294900/user7294900) you have to create catch blocks of specific exceptions first, and at the last, you have to use the general exception. If you use the general exception first then the specific exceptions would be unreachable and the compiler will throw an error saying

> error: exception InterruptedException has already been caught
> catch(InterruptedException e){

```
try {
  ---
  ---
}
catch(InterruptedException e) {
  specialTreatmentForThisException();
}
catch(Exception e){
  doStuff();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Exception is parent therefore children InterruptedException class is not used.
Change parent position  and children position.